# Does memory fragmentation leads to out of memory exception?

Tags: c++, memory-management, out-of-memory

Does memory fragmentation leads to "out of memory exception" or program and system can handle this issue at runtime?

Comment: Answer: Maybe and maybe. Next question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's theoretically possible for fragmentation to cause out-of-memory exceptions. Suppose you do lots of allocations of small objects that mostly fill your memory, then you delete every other object. This will produce a large total amount of free memory, but they'll all be very small blocks -- this is extreme fragmentation. If you try to allocate an object bigger than any of these blocks, the allocation will fail.

The runtime system generally can't fix this up, because in most implementations addresses in pointers can't be changed automatically. So allocations can't be rearranged to consolidate all the free space.

Good heap management implementations are designed to make this unlikely. One common technique is to use different areas of memory for different allocation sizes. Small allocations come from one area, medium allocations from another area, and large allocations from their own area. So if you get lots of fragmentation in the small area, it won't cause a problem for large allocations.